# Writing tests with RSpec for Redis with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, redis, capybara

I have a model class that caches data in redis. The first time I call a method on the model, it computes a JSON/Hash value and stores it in Redis. Under certain circumstances I 'flush' that data and it gets recomputed on the next call.

Here's the code snippet similar to the one I use to store the data in Redis:

```
def cache_data
  self.data_values = data_to_cache
  REDIS.set(redis_key,ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self.data_values))
  REDIS.get(redis_key) 
end

def data_to_cache
  # generate a hash of values to return
end
```

How should I unit test this code? I use RSpec and Capybara. I also use Cucumber and Capabara for integration testing if that helps.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I like to have redis running while the tests are running. Redis, unlike e.g. postgres, is extremely fast and doesn't slow down test run time noticeably.

Just make sure you call `REDIS.flush` in a `before(:each)` block, or the corresponding cucumber hook.

You can test `data_to_cache` independently of redis, but unless you can fully trust the redis driver you're using and the contract it provides, it's safer to actually test `cache_data` (and the corresponding cache fetch method) live.  That also allows you to switch to a different redis driver (or to a different fast KV store) without a wholesale rewrite of your tests.

Comment: I believe this is now `REDIS.flushdb`

Answer (score 23):

First of all add the below code in the spec_helper.rb so you'll be sure that the tests will run on any machine even if the redis server is not installed (make sure to add to your gemfile mock_redis under test scopes:

```
redis_instance = MockRedis.new
Redis.stub(:new).returns(redis_instance)
Redis::Store.stub(:new).returns(redis_instance)
```

After that I would test:

1. The data written to REDIS is the expected data
2. A sequence of cache_data, flush_data, cache_data calls the data_to_cache twice

Comment: So you'd recommend having redis running and actually testing the interaction of the data with redis. This puts a dependency of having redis running while tests are being run (which I'm not against in general). But it adds a dependency that I can see some might recommend handling with stubs.

Comment: Nope. That's MockRedis is doing ... it stores the data in memory so you don't need a redis server. I said "so you'll be sure that the tests will run on any machine even if the redis server is not installed".

Comment: One thing you might want to add to the top of this answer, which was very helpful is: add `gem 'mock_redis'` to your Gemfile and add this line to your spec_helper as well `require 'mock_redis'`

Comment: I have "undefined method `stubs' for Redis:Class (NoMethodError)". :(

Comment: @TiSir - Try calling `.stub(:new).and_return(redis_instance)` instead.

Comment: I think this is a bad choice to mock redis, which is super fast. A better option is to spin up a test redis server and use it instead. I created a gem that facilitate that: http://rubygems.org/gems/redis_test

Comment: I agree that running the tests without needing a redis server is valuable. I'd suggest setting the Resque redis instance to a MockRedis instance instead of stubbing it out though. Resque.redis = MockRedis.new

Comment: There are bugs in `mock_redis` even in 2019. It's a bad choice to use it :(

Answer (score 8):

Both the answers are outdated in May 2022. Following is the updated version with a sample test.

add this to `Gemfile`

```
gem 'mock_redis'
```

Install the `mock_redis` gem using

```
bundle install
```

In your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb` add this

```
require 'mock_redis'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  '''
  Creating a stub/mock Redis for running the tests without requiring an actual Redis server. This will store the Redis data in memory instead of the Redis server. 
  '''
  config.before(:each) do
    mock_redis = MockRedis.new
    allow(Redis).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_redis)
  end
end
```

This would make sure to mock Redis for all your test.

Let's say you have a module (`module_in_my_app.rb`) that uses Redis like so

```
module ModuleInMyApp
    extend self
    @@redis = Redis.new(url: "redis://#{ENV["REDIS_URL"]}")

    def get_or_create_my_key(keys, default_value)
       return @@redis.set(key, value)
    end

    def get_my_key(key)
       return @@redis.get(key)
    end
end
```

You can use it like so in your spec (`module_in_my_app_spec.rb`)

```
describe "test my redis module" do
    it "should set the key" do
        ModuleInMyApp.set_my_key("US", "United States of America")

        redis_var = class_variable_get(:@@redis)
        expect(redis_var.get("US")).to eq("United States of America")
    end

    it "should get the key" do
        mock_redis = Redis.new
        mock_redis.set("CA", "Canada")
        ModuleInMyApp.class_variable_set(:@@redis, mock_redis)

        actual_result = ModuleInMyApp.get_my_key("CA")
        expect(actual_result).to eq("Canada")
    end
end
```